# Wifi doesn't show up

Tags: wifi

I decided to install ElementaryOs alongside with Windows 10 (dual boot), and I have spend all day looking for an answer to my problem and nothing works.

If I open the settings on ElementaryOs it only shows on the side "Wired"/"VPN"/"Proxy" and nothing about Wi-Fi.

In the Windows 10 it works just fine.

I have tried this:

[image: dkms status]

[image: iwconfig]

[image: ifconfig -a]

[image: rfkill list]

My network card is Realtek. If you need any more info just ask.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my HP all in one, installed dual boot and low and behold wifi didn't work; furthermore, I didn't have wired connection available. This is how I solved my problem:

1. Inserted a generic dlink wifi usb dongle I had lying around and it was instantly recognized, this allowed me to access the internet.
2. I went into applications and opened AppCenter, this allowed me to search for and install "Software and Updates".
3. After running and installing all updates, I then ran a search for and installed "rtl8821ce-dkms". This was the missing driver I needed to recognize my wifi adapter.
4. Was then able to remove the dlink device and continue on my merry way. I believe I might have rebooted after one or two updates.